# Building multi arch docker image with tags

Tags: spring-boot, docker, x86, raspberry-pi4

Currently I have a spring application which was made to run on docker for which we have followed this documentation mentioned below:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

This I believe this command `docker build -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker .` builds an image for x86 platform only.

As I'm using an x86 machine for development, how does one build a docker image for arm and x86 in dockerCLI? As I wanted an image than can run on a server(x86) and Rpi(arm) with the appropriate tags like:

- org/app:x86
- org/app:arm

Comment: Have a look at the new feature [docker buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) to build multi-arch images. Also, Docker Registry stores multi-architecture images under the same tag and pull the one fitting to the client that executes the pull. There shouldn't really be a need anymore to tag images with architectue (x86, arm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the builds by adding a build argument. For example:

`docker build -t springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:arm32v7 --build-arg ARCH=arm32v7/ .`

A easier way to build the image for all required platforms with one cli instruction is to use the experimental build engine `buildx`. See also instructions on the [docker blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/)